# Topological Charge in 2 dimensional U(1) Gauge Theory

Tags: gauge-theory, topology

The topological charge in 2 dimensions for $U(1)$ gauge fields is defined by

$Q \propto \int d^2x ~\epsilon_{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$

with the field strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$.

For topological considerations, one usually states, that the gauge fields $A_\mu$ asymptotically become a pure gauge

$A_\mu \propto e^{-i\alpha(\phi)} \partial_\mu e^{i\alpha(\phi)} $

In many textbooks, e.g. in *Rajaraman - Solitons and Instantons*, we can find the statement that $Q$ is integer because

$ \int d^2x ~\epsilon_{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} \propto \oint_{S^1} \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{l} \propto \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi ~d\alpha/d\phi~.$

But this is $\alpha(2\pi)-\alpha(0)$ and should vanish due to periodicity. What am I missing and why does this give an integer without any explicit assumtion on the form of $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a compact variable. Meaning that $\alpha(2\pi) - \alpha(0)$ does not have to vanish but can take any value of $2n\pi$.